# How to allow YouTube object embed in Wordpress 3+?

Tags: html, embed, youtube, html5

I admin a Wordpress blog with a few dozens of users.  Since we upgraded to version 3.1+ my users can't insert the YouTube embed tags into a post ( wordpress or TinyMCE removes them ).

When I'm logged in as administrator, I can insert the ,  and  tags.  But my  users cannot.

What about the auto-embed ( oEmbed )?   Well, my users are too dumb to figure it out.  They get confused pasting the link on it's own line and making sure it's not hyperlinked.  The idea of adding [embed] tags around the URL is too difficult for them.

Basically, someone taught them how to copy the embed code and paste it into the HTML tab and that's all they know how to do.  They don't want to change.

How can I make them happy?  I just want to allow the YouTube embed code in their posts.  Any plugin or hack to do this?

Thanks, and my dumb users thank you too.

Comment: By the way, I added the "TinyMCE Advanced" plugin and I like how it allowed me to turn select "Do not remove HTML5 tags".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youtube now supports oEmbed  by default as the first option and even automatically highlights the url.

Go to the youtube video you want, click **share**, the url is auto highlighted for you, copy + paste into wordpress, it does not get any easier.

Comment: You can also go to Settings->Media and adjust the size of the auto embeds. To reiterate the above point, you don't need embed tags, only the URL.

Comment: I know, but my users are dumb.  They don't know how to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

I've used a plugin called YouTuber to solve this problem http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/youtuber/